# Sending a SOAP request to a web service using C#?

Tags: c#, python, web-services, soap

I am new to C# and my supervisor wants me to send a SOAP request to a web service and receive the connection string in C#. I have worked with Python before but I am really confused as how to do it in C#. This is the Python code I wrote. I am really lost.

```
import requests

url="http://172.20.3.3:8250/GS/GetConnectionStrings.asmx?WSDL"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
body = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                              <soap:Body>
                                <DatabaseConnectionString xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>
                                  <DatabaseName>LMA</DatabaseName>
                                </DatabaseConnectionString>
                              </soap:Body>
                            </soap:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
print response.content
```

I need to convert the above code to C#.

Comment: This is a very google-able topic, did you come to SO before researching? I will give you a tip, if you want to use RestSharp instead of built-in c# libraries you can set your request up in [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) and it can generate code for you in many different languages.

Comment: Aside: just a quick note on question style, Jessica. You will be very much aware that I've trimmed "please help me out" and similar from your earlier questions. It especially does not need adding twice to the same post. Please note that adding this sort of commentary does not get you answers any faster, and some readers may understand it as a form of begging. We know you want help - please keep it succinct if you can! Thanks.